# generateStaticParams not generating parent pages from child segment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

When using generateStaticParams from the bottom up ([like so](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#generate-params-from-the-bottom-up)) it doesn't look like the parent pages are being generated at build time.
Can anyone help?

I can visit the pages in local dev but visiting them in production will fail with:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
Digest: 3053036753
```

And in the browser console.

```
Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.
```

Also after running build and start to run the app locally, the pages return a 404 on visit and on prefetch.
So perhaps they are being dynamically generated in local dev?

Pages are being generated at: `/posts/[category]/[slug]/page.tsx`

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const { slugs } = await getPost();

  if (!slugs) {
    return [];
  }

  return slugs?.map(post => ({
    category: post?.category?.slug,
    slug: post?.slug,
  }));
}
```

`/posts/[category]/page.tsx`

```
export const revalidate = 1;

const PostCategoryPage = async ({
  params,
}: {
  params: { category: string };
}) => {
  console.log(params.category); // logs correctly
  return <PostsTemplate posts={await getAllPostsCategory(params.category)} />;
};

export default PostCategoryPage;
```

When running build it doesn't look like the `/posts/[category]` and `/skills/[category]` (skills uses the same pattern as posts) segments are generating any pages, if I am right this may be the issue.
But then why are they not being generated?

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      0 B                0 B
├ λ /api/disable-draft                     0 B                0 B
├ λ /api/draft                             0 B                0 B
├ λ /api/server                            0 B                0 B
├ ○ /feedback                              377 B           178 kB
├ ○ /posts                                 1.23 kB         492 kB
├ λ /posts/[category]                      1.22 kB         492 kB
├ ● /posts/[category]/[slug]               1.23 kB         492 kB
├   ├ /posts/react/react-post-3
├   ├ /posts/react/react-post-2
├   ├ /posts/react/react-post
├   └ [+9 more paths]
├ ○ /projects                              377 B           178 kB
├ ● /projects/[slug]                       377 B           178 kB
├   └ /projects/test-project
├ ○ /skills                                1.23 kB         492 kB
├ λ /skills/[category]                     377 B           178 kB
└ ● /skills/[category]/[slug]              1.23 kB         492 kB
    ├ /skills/technical/html
    ├ /skills/technical/react
    ├ /skills/personal/teamwork
    └ [+2 more paths]
+ First Load JS shared by all              77.9 kB
  ├ chunks/769-7cbae1b07f14e5e9.js         25.3 kB
  ├ chunks/bce60fc1-66cb623c49e35b22.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-88bacf2afcccecba.js    221 B
  └ chunks/webpack-fe7935db2da6851a.js     1.79 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   184 B            75 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              74.9 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-43665103d101a22d.js   45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-0b2a23c7f91d2529.js        27.8 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-1f2755172264764d.js  198 B
  └ chunks/webpack-fe7935db2da6851a.js     1.79 kB
```

Comment: Putting a generateStaticParams into [category] to generate those pages has worked. But doesn't seem right that both [category] and [slug] now both define `category` in their generateStaticParams